# How to add sorting by price on Sylius ProductController::indexByTaxon method

Tags: sorting, product, taxonomy, sylius, facet

How would I go about adding a simple 'order by price desc' or 'order by price asc' select menu to a category listing page on Sylius frontend?

In example - on demo page here: http://demo.sylius.org/t/category/mugs
There's:
- filtering by price

So far I've managed to figure out that this is done via facets and configured in sylius_search like like this:

```
sylius_search:
    ...
    filters:
        pre_search_filter:
            enabled: true
            taxonomy: category
        facet_groups:
            search_set:
                values: [taxons, price, made_of, color]
            categories_set:
                values: [price, made_of, color]
            all_set:
                values: [taxons, price, made_of]
        facets:
            taxons:
                display_name: 'Basic categories'
                type: terms
                value: ~
            price:
                display_name: 'Available prices'
                type: range
                values:
                    - { from: 0, to: 2000}
                    - { from: 2001, to: 5000}
                    - { from: 5001, to: 10000}
            made_of:
                display_name: 'Material'
                type: terms
                value: ~
            color:
                display_name: 'Available colors'
                type: terms
                value: ~
```

Any attempt to figure this out ended up as a dead end or bunch of errors.

I can override product repository and try passing request along to add custom leftJoin to Variants and then add orderBy on doctrine query builder, but I'm guessing this is hacking and wouldn't get me very far.

So in short, how do I add sorting options to product listing page(s) so I can have my products sorted using master variant price?

Any help or guide in the right direction appreciated.